# Scanner input, nothing happens

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Pollo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner carne = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type numbers:");
        int Numero = Integer.parseInt(carne.nextLine());
        while (Numero != -1) {

            if (Numero == -1) {
                System.out.println("Thank you and see you later!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem here is that if I type a number (or more), and then type -1, nothing happens.
If the first number is -1, then no message is displayed, and the process finishes with exit code 0.

What could possibly be wrong?

Comment: You're not getting any data in within the loop itself. You need to call `nextSomething()` on the Scanner within the loop and assign the input to your Numero variable. It makes sense that if Numero never changes, the loop never ends. Also, why use `nextLine()` when you could more easily use Scanner's `nextInt()`?

Comment: `if (Numero == -1) {` will never be true where it is

Comment: Also side issues: your question title should be informative, it should summarize your problem, not your assignment. And you'll want to learn and follow Java naming conventions. Variables should start with a lower-case letter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> type a number (or more), and then type -1, nothing happens

You never prompt again for input. The while loop is infinite and your extra  input is not processed.

> If the first number is -1, then no message is displayed, and the process finishes with exit code 0.

The while loop is never entered, and the program exits

Maybe you should try this

```
    System.out.println("Type numbers:");
    int Numero = Integer.parseInt(carne.nextLine());
    while (Numero != -1) {
        System.out.println("Type numbers:");
        Numero = Integer.parseInt(carne.nextLine());
        if (Numero == -1) {
```

Or even

```
int numero;
do {
     System.out.println("Type numbers:");
     numero = Integer.parseInt(carne.nextLine());
} while (numero != -1);
System.out.println('Thank you");
```

Comment: Just adding a second "Numero = Integer.parseInt(carne.nextLine());" to my while loop fixed the problem. I guess that does make sense. Thanks. And everyone who said I wasn't informative enough, you're right. My bad, I didn't get my 8 hours.